# Anyway to export all data for import into a local instance?

Tags: import, export, data

I know we can export contacts and activities but is there anyway to export everything (ex. activity types, custom contact fields, etc) so that I can import everything into a fresh Joomla/Civi install in my local development environment? I don’t have access to the remote database or website files themselves so I was hoping there was a native way to do this or perhaps a plugin or extension?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CiviCRM Configuration Loader extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-configuration-loader-extension-version-2) which will export / import a good deal of entities including contact types, relationship types, activity types, custom fields, campaign types, membership types, event types, case types, message templates and CiviRules.

Make sure you include the option groups with the custom fields they are a part of.